# How to configure Mqtt in Ruby On Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-mqtt

I am using MQTT for an application in which I am working with sensors and time series database. I have written some code which is working properly.I put the connection establishment inside scheduler. When server initializes it will automatically call a method where I wrote some code to connect to MQTT. But, Right now I am thinking it was not good. Please help on this. Instead of writing in scheduler how can I configure MQTT connection in a rails application.

Comment: Hey, I'm also stuck with similar problem now, do you know the solution now?

Answer (score 0):

Have you check this link? http://blog.mallow-tech.com/2016/11/iot-in-rails-with-aws-mqtt/
Here it shows how to use mqtt with rails using a ruby gem https://rubygems.org/gems/mqtt